# MatPlotLib imshow() muestra la imagen muy agrandada, ampliada o con zoom

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

Me encuentro mostrando una sección de una imagen en un `axis` con `MatPlotLib imshow()`, pero por lo que puedo ver, la imagen se muestra muy agrandada en el `axis`. Veo que la imagen no se esta ajustando a los valores de los `set_xlim` y `set_xticks` que se especifican.

**Así tengo configurado el axis:**

```
ax52=ax[4].twiny()
ax52.set_xlim(-10, 110)
ax52.set_xticks([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
ax52.xaxis.grid(False)
ax52.yaxis.grid(False)
ax52.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

**Y de esta manera tengo configurada para que me muestre la imagen:**

```
image2 = None
image2 = ax52.imshow(Image.open(pathDir + 'Sand.png'), cmap=plt.cm.gray, extent=[0, 100, top_depth, top_depth+ 1000])
poly2 = ax52.fill_betweenx(ControlStart2['DEPTH'], ControlStart2['Sand'], ControlEnd2['Sand'], facecolor='none', visible=True)
clip2 = poly2.get_paths()[0] 
image2.set_clip_path(clip2, transform=ax52.transData)
```

**Así se ve la imagen original a la que hago referencia:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y así se ve en la grafica:**

Por lo que se ve que la imagen en la grafica se ha hecho un tipo de zoom que no se, porque aparece, ya que la imagen sobre el axis se visualiza desde valores menores de 0 y mayores a 100, lo que significa que sobrepasa los ejes especificados con anterioridad. También, recalcar que lo que se ve como una zona marcada con color negro seria la parte de la grafica que no se logra ver en el axis ya que la imagen esta demasiado ampliada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En conclusión: Los datos y la presentación de la grafica son correctos, pero al momento de aparecer dentro del axis, pues no toma en cuenta los valores de `extent=[0, 100, top_depth, top_depth+ 1000]`, si no que se sobrepasan a los ejes establecidos en el axis que fueron configurados anteriormente.

El resultado final que necesito seria como el siguiente:

1. Que la imagen este ajustada y no se presente con zoom.
2. Que la imagen se encuentre dentro de los limites de los ejes x.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que necesitás es cambiar el tamaño de la imagen, lo que vos estás haciendo es limitar el xlim entre `[10,110]` eso es equivalente a solo mirar esa parte de la imagen. Tenés conocimiento de alguna librería de procesamiento de imágenes?